# Redirect state in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, state, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework, rootscope

**This is the state configuration:**

```
angular
    .module('grabhutApp', [...])
    .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $stateProvider
            // ACCOUNT
            .state('account', {
                abstract: true,
                url: '/account',
                templateUrl: 'index.html'
            })
            .state('account.main', {
                url: '',
                templateUrl: 'views/account/account.login.html',
                controller: 'AccountController'
            })
            .
            .
            .
            // NO VIEWS
            .state('nv', {
                abstract: true,
                url: '/nv'
            })
            .state('nv.logout', {
                url: '/logout'
            })  
    });
```

The `nv` and its sub states will have no physical views or controllers.
I want them to serve as links that calls certain functions.

**Service for calling logout methods:**

```
angular.module('grabhutApp')
    .factory('$grabhutAccountService', function ($state, $grabhutDataService) {

        var methods = {     
            .
            .
            logoutUser: function () {
                $grabhutDataService.user.removeSession();
                $state.go('account.main', {}, {location: 'replace'});
            }
            .
            .
        };

        return methods;
    });
```

**Then a button/link for logout:**

```
<a ui-sref="nv.logout" class="button icon icon ion-log-out button-large" menu-close></a>
```

What I want to happen is that, when state `nv.logout` was triggered the
`$grabhutAccountService.logoutUser()` must be called and must redirect to `'account.main'`

Here is what I've done so far:
**I tried to use resolve in `nv.logout`**

```
.state('nv.logout', {
    url: '/logout',
    resolve: {
        logout: function ($grabhutAccountService) {
            $grabhutAccountService.logoutUser();
        }
    }
})
```

The service was called but state did not redirect. So I tried another way. I added a controller:

```
.state('nv.logout', {
    url: '/logout',
    resolve: {
        logout: function ($grabhutAccountService) {
            $grabhutAccountService.logoutUser();
        }
    },
    controller: function ($scope, $state) {
        $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function () {
            $state.go('account.main');          
        });
    }   
})
```

But `$stateChangeSuccess` is not being fired.
**So I tried to use the rootScope:**

```
.run(function(...., $grabhutAccountService){

    .
    .
    .
    $rootScope.logout = function(){
        $grabhutAccountService.logoutUser();
    };
    .
    .
    .

})
```

**And the use it like this:**

`<a ng-click="$root.logout()" class="button icon icon ion-log-out button-large" menu-close></a>`

This works fine. But I'm worrying since (AFAIK) rootScope loads more data which could cause slower operation.
Besides, whenever I need some kind of function like above, I would have to attach function in rootScope again.
And I think that's not a good approach. BTW, I'm building this in phonegap that's why memory usage is so important.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ooooh you're so close.  I rearranged some of your code and arrived at this:

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $grabhutAccountService) {
   $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (evt, toState) {
     if (toState.name === 'nv.logout') {
       $grabhutAccountService.logoutUser();
       $state.go('account.main');
     }  
   });
});
```

The next major version of UI-Router will have much improved hooks for doing this sort of thing.